# jQuery - Adding / Removing Input Fields in Form

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, input

I've searched and I could not find an answer to solve my problem here. I am fairly noobish with jQuery, and I am looking to add/remove input fields from two different areas. I've tried editing my jQuery and HTML code to accommodate the second part I want to add/remove (the items found), but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd2').click(function() {
                var num2        = $('.clonedInput2').length;    //     how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num2 + 1);     // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

            // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem2 = $('#input2' + num2).clone().attr('id', 'input2' + newNum);

            // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
            newElem2.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).val(null);

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#input2' + num2).after(newElem2);

            // enable the "remove" button
            $('#btnDel2').attr('disabled','');

        });

        $('#btnDel2').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput2').length;    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#input2' + num).remove();        // remove the last element

            // enable the "add" button
            $('#btnAdd2').attr('disabled','');

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel2').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel2').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="process_call.php" method="post">
        <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
            Charge: <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name1" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Another Charge" />
            <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove Charge" />
        </div>

        <div id="input2" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput2">
            Item Found: <input type="text" name="item[]" id="item1" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd2" value="Add Another Item" />
            <input type="button" id="btnDel2" value="Remove Item" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the selector `$('#input2' + num2)` when the script is executed first, there is only one element with id `input2`, but your selector is looking for an element with id `input21` which does not exits.

I fixed it by cloning the last element with class `clonedInput2` instead of finding the element with `id`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#btnAdd2').click(function () {
        var num2 = $('.clonedInput2').length; //     how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum = num2 + 1; // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem2 = $('.clonedInput2:last').clone().attr('id', 'input2' + newNum);

        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        newElem2.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).val(null);

        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('.clonedInput2:last').after(newElem2);

        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel2').prop('disabled', false);

    });

    $('#btnDel2').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput2').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#input2' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd2').attr('disabled', '');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DbCmW/)

Comment: Thank you much! I had to make a couple small edits to fix the remove button not working with your code, but works excellent!